# Docker file command runs apt-get update from wrong repository

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I could not install the postgresql 9.5 This is the point when I'm in the docker file
Dockerfile row

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.5 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends
```

and it runs the command bellow.

```
remote: E: Package 'postgresql-client-9.5' has no installation candidate
remote:
 The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -qq 
-y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.5 --fix-missing 
--no-install-recommends' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Seems that it tries to do apt-get update from  debian repository when I'm on ubuntu xenial. May be something went wrong because I installed first wrong docker version for debian , and then I removed the debian docker with

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

After this I have installed the docker for my ubuntu xenial distribution. I don't understand why when I run the docker file it still updates the packages and tries to install packages that are for debian, when I don't have anything debian related?

The installed docker version is

```
Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
```

From https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/pool/main/d/docker-engine/docker-engine_17.05.0~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb

Here is the code when it runs apt-get update:

```
remote:  ---> Running in b8d8101adf4a
remote:  ---> f9286d1e85d1
remote: Removing intermediate container b8d8101adf4a
remote: Step 3/11 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.5 mysql-client-5.7 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends
remote:  ---> Running in 9bda34235687
remote: Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
remote: Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
remote: Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
remote: Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
remote: Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [12.1 kB]
remote: Get:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [440 kB]
remote: Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
remote: Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [9530 kB]
remote: Fetched 10.3 MB in 13s (789 kB/s)
remote: Reading package lists...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
MAINTAINER Makkasi <makkasi@abv.bg>

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.5 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /project1
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

VOLUME ["static"]
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 "project1.app:create_app()"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
postgres:
  image: postgres:9.5
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: makkasi
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepassword
  ports:
    - '5432:5432'
  volumes:
    - ~/.docker-volumes/project1/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


redis:
  image: redis:2.8.22
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - ~/.docker-volumes/project1/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data

project1:
  build: .
  command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --access-logfile - "project1.app:create_app()"
  environment:
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED: true
  links:
    - postgres
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/project1
  ports:
    - '8000:8000'
```

Comment: Please include your full Dockerfile in the question. The repo used during an image build depends on the base image selected, not the host.

Comment: @BMitch In the Dockerfile there is nothing specific to postgress. In the docker compose there is postgres 9.5. If I understand correctly the repostiroty type is determine by first image in the docker-compose file and that is postgres. From there what it is the repository depends on the postgres Dockerfile. Is that  correct?

Comment: Please include the full Dockerfile in your question.

Comment: @BMitch I have added the rest. I'm sorry but I'm new to this and thought that the rest of the Dockerfile is not important. It's just the gunicorn command. There is nothing else in the file. Neither in Dockerfile neither in docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems that it tries to do apt-get update from debian repository when I'm on ubuntu xenial.

Commands to build an image are run within a container based on the previous state of the image. They do not depend on the host you are running on. The result is the same image could be built on different docker host with nearly identical results (external dependencies and timestamps being the normal exceptions). If you follow the path of the Dockerfile you've provided from the `FROM` lines, you get:

- `FROM python:2.7`: [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/4d640edc8df64b9cf050904f60ac03765e05d3f6/2.7/stretch/Dockerfile)
- `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch`: [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps/) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/d7da72aaf3bb93fecf5fcb7c6ff154cb0c55d1d1/stretch/Dockerfile)
- `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-scm`: [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps/) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/1845b3f918f69b4c97912b0d4d68a5658458e84f/stretch/scm/Dockerfile)
- `FROM buildpack-deps:stretch-curl`: [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/buildpack-deps/) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/b0fc01aa5e3aed6820d8fed6f3301e0542fbeb36/stretch/curl/Dockerfile)
- `FROM debian:stretch`: [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/) and [Dockerfile](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/b024a792c752a5c6ccc422152ab0fd7197ae8860/stretch/Dockerfile)

You can also run a container based on your base image and use the standard package manager tools to query for what versions of packages are included (this is particularly useful when you don't have the Dockerfile for your image):

```
$ docker run -it --rm python:2.7 /bin/bash

root@ea64878fc27f:/# cat /etc/debian_version
8.7

root@ea64878fc27f:/# apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [94.4 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease                   
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]              
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2434 B]                            
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]               
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [623 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.0 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]           
Fetched 10.1 MB in 9s (1058 kB/s)                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done

root@ea64878fc27f:/# apt-cache search postgresql-client
postgresql-client-9.4 - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 9.4
postgresql-client - front-end programs for PostgreSQL (supported version)
postgresql-client-common - manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions

root@ea64878fc27f:/# apt-cache madison postgresql-client
postgresql-client | 9.4+165+deb8u3 | http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
postgresql-client | 9.4+165+deb8u3 | http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2):

I think is a postgresql version question.
If you're using `stretch` or `buster` (buster actually updates from stretch servers), version found in repo is **postgresql-client-9.6**, not 9.5.

Try with this and we see.

Comment: Thank you. Version 9.6 worked, but I didn't undertand how you find what are the allowed versions. For example if the first image in docker-compose is postgress but the second one is mysql , then how to find what version for mysql is allowed/accesible. There is also useful comment below my question. It helped me to understand what is going on. I suggest you to add it to your answer. Thank you.

Comment: If my comment solved your question, please, mark it as solved. 
The only way to avoid these issues about versions is have latest versions of everything or create a repo with versions of debian 9, 8, 7...
If program what you want to install is old, is better specify versions of SO and programs.